# How to filter an array based on the grand child array's values?

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6, angular8

I am trying to filter the parent array based on the grand child array's values, but my filtering approach doesn't work well and the UI is not getting updated.

Here is my filter function.

```js
filterIt($event) {
    this.filter.RegCategoryName = $event.target.value;
    this.dataObject = staticData.filter(value => 
        value.List.filter(ch => ch.RegistrationCategory.filter(gChild =>
            Object.keys(this.filter).every(ob => 
                String(gChild[ob]).toLowerCase().includes(String(this.filter[ob]).toLowerCase())
            )
        )).length
    )
}
```

[Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6hrhje)

**Expectation:**

When the user types `new Course`, it should only show `DP Programme` in Programme column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using a combination of [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) `Array` methods. Use the spread operator `...` so that your original array does not get updated in the child objects.

```js
filterIt($event) {
    this.filter.RegCategoryName = $event.target.value;
    this.dataObject = staticData.filter(value => {
        const data = { ...value };
        data.List = data.List.map(ch => {
            const list = { ...ch };
            list.RegistrationCategory = list.RegistrationCategory.filter(gChild => {
                return gChild.RegCategoryName.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.filter.RegCategoryName.toLowerCase()) !== -1
            });
            return list;
        });
        return data.List.some(list => !!list.RegistrationCategory.length);
    });
}
```

**Note**: Avoid using variable names with the first letter capitalized.

Here is a working example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-filter-array-based-on-child).

**Explanation**:

The structure used here is pretty complicated so I guess I'll start from inside out. Let's start out with the innermost `filter`.

```js
list.RegistrationCategory = list.RegistrationCategory.filter(gChild => {
    return gChild.RegCategoryName.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.filter.RegCategoryName.toLowerCase()) !== -1
});
```

> The **`filter()`** method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

This one should be clear enough. The condition used here is the same one used in Angular Material's `mat-table` filter. This will filter if `RegCategoryName` contains the search term. I say contain because this will match `new Course` even if your search term is `ew`. If this is not what you desire, you can use `startsWith` instead. This will only match if your search term is `new` and not `ew`.

```js
list.RegistrationCategory = list.RegistrationCategory.filter(gChild => {
    return gChild.RegCategoryName.toLowerCase().startsWith(this.filter.RegCategoryName.toLowerCase())
});
```

Moving on to the first parent array `List`. We do not want to `filter` or change the objects in here. Instead, we just want the same object but with the new filtered `RegistrationCategory`. This fits well for a `map` since `map` returns an array with the same number of objects(with some modification to the elements within the object if desired).

> The **`map()`** method **creates a new array** with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

So in our `map` we will update `RegistrationCategory` using the `filter` we created above. We cannot modify `ch` directly since that would mutate the original object. So instead we will shallow clone `ch` using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals) into a variable `list`, modify `RegistrationCategory` in our new `list` variable using the above `filter` and return the object. This now gives us the `List` array as is by just updating `RegistrationCategory` in each object.

Now for the final piece, we need to `filter` through `staticData`. As we did in the `map`, we will use the spread syntax here again as we do not want to update the original object. `data.List` will now have each `RegistrationCategory` filtered thanks to our innermost filter, so we just need to return a `true`/`false` value based on whether the `List` array has any object whose `RegistrationCategory` length is more than 0. We can use `some` for this.

> The **`some()`** method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function. It returns a Boolean value.

So if any `RegistrationCategory` in the `List` array has length more than 0(since that's all we care about, whether any `RegistrationCategory` is still present after our innermost filter has filtered `List`), it returns `true` and is added to the filtered `dataObject`.

This way we get each object in `staticData` whose `List` array contains an object where `RegistrationCategory` has some data.

I hope this makes it clear why you were having issues with your code and why you cannot use a filter for all three arrays.

Comment: I thrown with error, can you please update in demo? - thanks in advacne

Comment: Sure, I have added it to my answer

Comment: works great. really your are a genius. But i don't know how to mix all this map, filter and some with properly. where can i lean that? what is the logic behind?

Comment: As a clarification, why my function not works? what was the blocker? can  you help me to understand? as well can you detail your steps with reason you kept in ? - just want to learn and help others from like persons you!!

Comment: Aw shucks , I just picked it up on the way I guess. The docs really help though, I'll add the links to the docs in my answer. You should also consider reading up on dealing with immutable data.

Comment: I have added an explanation to my answer. Hope it clears things out :)

Comment: best wishes to you.. thanks for made me understand the complexity.